# Abandoning (conventional) lexical class

Tags: chomsky, minimalism, universal-grammar

I am curious to know more about approaches to linguistics that aren’t centrally based on central word classes like nouns, verbs, etc. Instead of taking them as important categories, there could actually be a more fine-grained distinction between all words - the categorization can be more decentralized, less top-down, more hierarchical, less flat.

I only know two examples that might approach this.

I am pretty sure the Minimalist Program reduced the language faculty to a single structural “function” called “merge”. Merge is set union: for two elements a, b, compose them into a new element (a, b). What is really interesting is, I read Chomsky suggested that there is a second specifier function which chooses which element is the set is the head. This is a really compelling idea to me because it allows the system to have either the properties of unordered or ordered sets, and it seems different aspects of language sometimes exhibit order (syntax) or non-order (aspects of semantics).

I don’t know where Chomsky takes the MP from here. What additional structure does he assert, on LF? Or is the “program” to encourage reformulating linguistics - any subdiscipline - in terms of that much simpler compositional structure (including phonology, morphology, maybe even pragmatics, discourse, etc.)? Is LF actually that simple, in MP?

Wouldn’t this be a radical self-refutation by Chomsky? It sounds like abandoning UG to the smallest structure possible that could enable, basically, any kind of recursive information structure. It sounds like he abandons pretty much the entire theory of syntax. Unless there is more to the theory.

I find the idea compelling, that the structure of language is a direct result of the language of thought. It sounds purer and simpler.

It would imply a lot of the features of language can be explained as naturally arising - constructed more stochastically than say, a transformation-grammar approach - but they converge to similar forms for far deeper psychological reasons, because they have to fill the mold of human thought anyway, the world humans live in, the type of beings they are (a sense of self, agency, feelings, a “theory of mind” in other people, object persistence, a sense of time, direction, that objects can differ in their qualities, etc.)

I don’t know if this would imply ordinary lexical classes like “nouns” don’t need to exist that strongly. We might instead see how similar word objects end up getting constructed in parallel - not because they are cut from the same cloth, but because they end up in the same place. But it can explain more fine-grained variety between the behaviors of different words.

It also reminds me of Head-driven phrase structure grammar. What I have seen if it is, extremely more elaborate annotations of a wide variety of functions and properties every word in the grammar has. It also goes far beyond the idea of simple classes like “noun” and “verb”, specifying each one more individually.

The weird thing is, I believe Geoffrey Pullum has written disparagingly about the minimalism program, and highly about Ivan Sag and HPSG, so I am curious in what way they are fundamentally opposed, if they are. Are they not reconcilable? Wouldn’t HPSG be an “a fortiori” grammar - describing the resultant forms of English as we know it, not an underlying “language faculty”?

Comment: It’s my lucky day! Robert D. Borsley & Stefan Müller. 2021. HPSG and Minimalism. In Stefan Müller, Anne Abeillé, Robert D. Borsley & Jean-Pierre Koenig (eds.), Head- Driven Phrase Structure Grammar: The handbook, 1253–1329. Berlin: Language Science Press. DOI: 10.5281/zenodo.5599874

Comment: https://hpsg.hu-berlin.de/~stefan/Pub/unifying-everything.pdf